# Is there a system behind VSCode keybindings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been using VSCode for a few weeks now and I love it.

However, whenever I learn a new shortcut I often get the feeling that they were selected "randomly", which means to me it feels that for each new functionality an almost arbitrary available key binding was selected. Some examples:

`Ctrl+K Ctrl+S` open the keybindings table

`Ctrl+K S` save all files

`Ctrl+Shift+K` delete line

It is hard for me to memorize all those shortcuts, so I am asking: Is there a system to all this that may help understand and memorize the keybindings?

And as part of this: Is there a difference between `Ctrl+K ...` shortcuts and other shortcuts?

Comment: Hi! You could just give your own keyboard shortcuts for the ones you need most. It's not necessary to memorize the ones given. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Thanks @Joey, I know this can be done. I mainly want to know if there is a system behind this. Also, someone must have started with this `Ctrl+K` thing and I want to learn why this was introduced.